# Symantec BE: How is data flow of backups/restore to storage pools?

Tags: backup, symantec

I am evaluating Symantec's BackupExec 2012 and was wondering how does the backup data flow from the server that as being backed up to the storage pool.

E.g. My BE server is in city A, the server that I am backing up is in city B and the storage pool that I plan to use is also located in city B.

When performing a backup, does the backup data flow from the server in city B to the BE server in city A and back to the storage pool in city B or is it possible to have the backup data go directly from server in city B to storage pool in city B?